# Javascript getting a variable from an Object

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have a problem getting the invoice number and invoice line number into a variable.

```
<script>
const emma = '<%=http2.ResponseText%>';
const obj = JSON.parse(emma);
console.log("object: %O", obj);
console.log(parameters["parameters"][1]["iInvoiceNum"]);
</script>
```

This is how the console displays. I just want to be able to pass the iInvoiceNum and iInvoiceLine  into separate variables.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use Classic ASP string in client side Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744878/how-do-you-use-classic-asp-string-in-client-side-javascript)

Comment: You have the object structure in the screenshot follow that and you can't go wrong. Did you even try `obj.parameters.ds.iInvoiceNum`?

Comment: You could just have used the dev tools console to test what works e.g. `obj.parameters` and see what was returned, like already said you have the structure of the object already there for you to play with, dev tools are great for that sort of thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access properties of object after JSON.parse()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52123802)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but should work:

```
const emma = '<%=http2.ResponseText%>';
const obj = JSON.parse(emma);
const invoiceLine = obj['parameters']['ds']['iInvoiceLine'];
const invoiceNr = obj['parameters']['ds']['iInvoiceNum'];
```

Alternative:

```
const emma = '<%=http2.ResponseText%>';
const obj = JSON.parse(emma);
const invoiceLine = obj.parameters.ds.iInvoiceLine;
const invoiceNr = obj.parameters.ds.iInvoiceNum;
```

Comment: Why not just `obj.parameters.ds.iInvoiceNum`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const emma = '<%=http2.ResponseText%>';
code hereconst obj = JSON.parse(emma);    
const { iInvoiceLine, iInvoiceNum } = obj.parameters.ds;
```

Comment: This is closer to what I would use personally.